# Received "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" when creating .zip file using ZipFile

Tags: c#, httpclient, webrequest, zip

I am trying to create a large .zip file using the ZipFile library in C#. 
Multiple music files are downloaded from URL by HttpClient and added in the zip loop.

For that, I follow for-loop > HttpClient to download music > add in zip > save zip.

Here, 30-35 music files will work perfectly. But i faced an issue when i have more than 35+ files. I want to create zip with minimum 500+ files.

I have an exception stored in logfile.txt.

The exception:

```
Action:The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.  Controller:   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save()
   at Groove.Libraries.Api.DonwloadMusic.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<DownloadMusicFilesByScheduler>b__2(StudioEventEntryDetailsResponseModel y)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at Groove.Libraries.Api.DonwloadMusic.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<DownloadMusicFilesByScheduler>b__0(StudioMusicDetails x)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at Groove.Libraries.Api.DonwloadMusic.DownloadMusicFilesByScheduler()
```

**Exception is thrown by zip.Save(string.Format("{0}/{1}", tempPath, archiveFileName)); line.**

Is there any problem with WebRequest or ZipFile Library?.

```
    // Get list of music files url
    EventMusicList eventEntryList = _globLib.GetEventMusicList(dbEvent.Id);

    // zip file name
    string archiveFileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}-Music.zip", eventEntryList.SeasonName,eventEntryList.EventName);

    ZipFile zip;

    // if zip Exists then get zip and add new music in this file OR create new zip
    if (File.Exists(string.Format("{0}/{1}", tempPath, archiveFileName)))
    {
          zip = new ZipFile(string.Format("{0}/{1}", tempPath, archiveFileName));
    }
    else
    {
          zip = new ZipFile();
    }

    // Start : Looping of music files url
    eventEntryList.StudioList.ForEach(
        x => x.EntryList.ToList().Where(y => y.Document.Id != 0 && !y.Document.IsDownloaded).ToList().ForEach(y =>
        {

           // get music file url from dropbox.
           DBB.GenerateAccessToken();
           var _link = DBB.GetFileTemporaryLink(y.Document.RootPath, y.Document.FileName);

           if (!_link.Equals(string.Empty))
           {  
               // Get Stream from music url - function is created at bottom 
               Stream stream = GetStreamFromUrl(_link);

               string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(y.Document.FileUrl);
               string fileName = y.EntryNumber != null
                   ? string.Format("{0}-{1}{2}", y.EntryNumber, y.Title, fileExtension)
                   : string.Format("{0}{1}", y.Title, fileExtension);
               if (zip.Entries.Where(z => z.FileName == fileName).Count() == 0)
               {
                   // add in zip
                   zip.AddEntry(fileName, stream);
               }
           }
           else
           {
               return;
           }

       // Check temporary path is exist or not, if not then create temporary folder
       if (!Directory.Exists(tempPath))
       {
           Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);
       }

       this.LogRequest("Save:-BeforeSave", "DownloadMusicLib");

       //Task t = Task.Run(() => { zip.Save(string.Format("{0}/{1}", tempPath, archiveFileName)); });
       //t.Wait();

       // Save zip file
       zip.Save(string.Format("{0}/{1}", tempPath, archiveFileName));

       this.LogRequest("Save:-AfterSave", "DownloadMusicLib");

    })); // END : Looping of music files url


    // New function to get stream from url
    public static Stream GetStreamFromUrl(string url)
    {
        byte[] imageData = null;
        Stream ms;
        ms = null;
        try
        {
            using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                imageData = wc.DownloadData(url);
            }
            ms = new MemoryStream(imageData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //forbidden, proxy issues, file not found (404) etc
        }
        return ms;
    }
```

[Screenshot of zip folder location, some are currepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMUik.png)

Here, I am getting temporary music file url from dropbox and get stream by using HttpClient.

When error occurs, zip file is courrpt. like '2018 - 2019-Washington IL Regional Competition-Music.zip.ugmf5uat.1a4'

Comment: Note that this particular error message is famously somewhat incorrect/incomplete. This error message/exception is not only given if another process has an open file handle on the file (with the handle not allowing sharing, and thus locking the file) your program is trying to open. The same error message is _also_ given in situations where your **own program** has already an open file handle (that again is not allowing sharing access to the file) to the same file, thus preventing it from being opened a second time.

Comment: In your case, note how your program creates a ZipFile object that uses the file denoted by archiveFileName. Then, when your program calls zip.Save, it tries to rename/move the originally existing ZIP file _archiveFileName_, but since it still being in use by the ZipFile itself, the move operation fails. Unfortunately, it seems to be a limitation of the _Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save(string filePath)_ method which is not aware that you are simply trying to update the ZIP file it already is using. Try calling `zip.Save()` without explicitly providing the ZIP file path argument and see whether it helps.